# Logging formatters in django

Tags: python, django, logging

From the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#examples), here is an example format for logging:

```
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s: %(message)s'
    }
}
```

This prints something like:

> ERROR 2012-05-22 14:33:07,261 views 42892 4398727168 hello

Is there a list of items you can include in the string formatting? For example, I'd like to be able to see the function and app where the message is being created, for example:

> ERROR time myproject.myapp.views.login_function message

Answer (score 43):

From [Python logging module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes):

- **asctime**: `%(asctime)s`
  Human-readable time when the [`LogRecord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord) was created. By default this is of the form ‘2003-07-08 16:49:45,896’ (the numbers after the comma are millisecond portion of the time).
- **created**: `%(created)f`
  Time when the [`LogRecord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord) was created (as returned by [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time)).
- **filename**: `%(filename)s`
  Filename portion of **pathname**.
- **funcName**: `%(funcName)s`
  Name of function containing the logging call.
- **levelname**: `%(levelname)s`
  Text logging level for the message ('DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'CRITICAL').
- **levelno**: `%(levelno)s`
  Numeric logging level for the message (DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL).
- **lineno**: `%(lineno)d`
  Source line number where the logging call was issued (if available).
- **module**: `%(module)s`
  Module (name portion of **filename**).
- **msecs**: `%(msecs)d`
  Millisecond portion of the time when the [`LogRecord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord) was created.
- **message**: `%(message)s`
  The logged message, computed as `msg % args`. This is set when [`Formatter.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.format) is invoked.
- **name**: `%(name)s`
  Name of the logger used to log the call.
- **pathname**: `%(pathname)s`
  Full pathname of the source file where the logging call was issued (if available).
- **process**: `%(process)d`
  Process ID (if available).
- **processName**: `%(processName)s`
  Process name (if available).
- **relativeCreated**: `%(relativeCreated)d`
  Time in milliseconds when the [`LogRecord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord) was created, relative to the time the logging module was loaded.
- **thread**: `%(thread)d`
  Thread ID (if available).
- **threadName**: `%(threadName)s`
  Thread name (if available).

The following arguments are also available to [`Formatter.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.format), although they are not intended to be included in the format string:

- **args**:
  The tuple of arguments merged into **msg** to produce message.
- **exc_info**:
  Exception tuple (à la [`sys.exc_info`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info)) or, if no exception has occurred, `None`.
- **msg**:
  The format string passed in the original logging call. Merged with **args** to produce message, or an arbitrary object (see [Using arbitrary objects as messages](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#arbitrary-object-messages)).

Answer (score 4):

Step1. Edit your settings.py file

```
$ cd mysite
$ vim mysite/settings.py
'formatters': {
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s- %(message)s'
    },
},
```

Step2. You should use logger in your coding like this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def fn1() {
    logger.info('great!')
    logger.info(__name__)
}
```

Hope that helps you!