# How to set a dirname and file instead of filepath or filename in Django logging?

Tags: python, django, logging, path, python-logging

We are looking to log the path of the file being logged.

For example I have the file views.py - this file name is repeated in the many applications of a Django project thus we need the file name to include the app name - polls\views.py
On the other hand we don't want the full absolute path..

This is the format line:

**format": "{levelname}: {message} at {asctime} in {filename} {funcName} {lineno} (process={process: d}, thread={thread:d})"**

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710591/logging-formatters-in-django) we only have the following related options: filename, module, and pathname which do not suffice.

Have not found help from [Django logging docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/)

Also tried string manipulating with {os.path.dirname(pathname)} but it doesn't appear to parse right

We get

```
    raise ValueError('Unable to configure '
ValueError: Unable to configure formatter 'verbose'
```

This is the LOGGING snippet from our settings.py:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            "format": "{levelname}: {message} at {asctime} in {filename} {funcName} {lineno} (process={process: d}, thread={thread:d})",
            "style": "{",
        },
        'default': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)s - %(lineno)d => %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'error_file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': f'logs/error_{datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}.log',
        },
        'info_file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': f'logs/info_{datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}.log',
        },
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'default',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'error_logger': {
            'handlers': ['error_file', 'console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'info_logger': {
            'handlers': ['info_file', 'console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use extra context as describe in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10294761/12545861).

In your views, add your app as extra context:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def my_function():
    app_name = 'my_app'  # Replace with your app name
    logger.info('This is a log message', extra={'app_name': app_name})
```

In your settings.py, add '{app_name}' in your formatter, for example:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            "**format": "{levelname}: {message} at {asctime} in {filename} {funcName} {lineno} (process={process: d}, thread={thread:d})"**,
            "style": "{",
        },
        'default': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)s - %(lineno)d => %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
        # Add a new formatter for including the app_name with your desired format
        'app_formatter': {
            'format': '{levelname}: {message} {asctime} {module} {app_name} {filename} {funcName} {lineno} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'error_file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': f'logs/error_{datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}.log',
        },
        'info_file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': f'logs/info_{datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}.log',
        },
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'app_formatter',  # Use the new app_formatter
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'error_logger': {
            'handlers': ['error_file', 'console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'info_logger': {
            'handlers': ['info_file', 'console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Great! and for the full solution:
app_name = __ file __
app_name = app_name.replace(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(app_name)), '')